# How to minify 3 loops or query to mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql

On a server I have a table with data like these:

```
+-----------+----------+-----------+-------------+-------------+--------+
| problemId | book     | chapter   | title       | options     | answer |
+-----------+----------+-----------+-------------+-------------+--------+
|         1 | Addition | Chapter 1 | 8 + 8 = ?   | 18,17,16,15 |     16 |
|         2 | Addition | Chapter 1 | ? + 12 = 18 | 15,17,16,6  |      6 |
|        15 | Addition | Chapter 2 | ? + 3 = 19  | 15,17,16,6  |     16 |
|        16 | Mixed    | Chapter 1 | ? + 3 = 19  | 15,17,16,6  |     16 |
+-----------+----------+-----------+-------------+-------------+--------+
```

I want to return a hash table like:

```
{
  'Addition': {
    'Chapter 1': [
      {
        title: ' 8 + 8 =',
        options: '18,17,16,15',
        answer: '16'
      },
      {
        // ...
      }
    ],
    'Chapter 2': [
      // ...
    ]
  },
  'Mixed': {
    // ...
  }
}
```

So I start with query to mysql `SELECT * FROM problem;` and using JavaScript re-format a result from MySQL:

```
var result = {};
var len = rows.length;

for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  result[rows[i].book] = {};
}

for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  result[rows[i].book][rows[i].chapter] = [];
}

for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
  result[rows[i].book][rows[i].chapter].push({
    title: rows[i].title,
    options: rows[i].options,
    answer: rows[i].answer
  });
}
```

Can I minify my 3 loops to re-format data or can I update my query to mysql?

Comment: what your question is? you want to write sql query for that or what?

Comment: @llamerr my question is can I minify my 3 loops to re-format data or can I update my query to mysql to get a data in format that I present?

Answer (score 1):

By using ES6 spread, you can do something like this.

```
const result = rows.reduce((table, cur) => {
  const chapter = table[cur.book] ? table[cur.book][cur.chapter] || [] : [];
  chapter.push({
    title: cur.title,
    options: cur.options,
    answer: cur.answer
  });

  return {
    ...table,
    [cur.book]: {
      ...table[cur.book],
      [cur.chapter]: chapter
    }
  };
}, {});
```

[DEMO fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6vfxzn3n/)

Answer (score 1):

### USE SQL TO OUTPUT JSON

You might modify your SQL so that it outputs json directly. This [MYSQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e288d0/1) duplicates your table and uses [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) and [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) to build a json string. Note that MySQL version 5.7 has some additional [json functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-functions.html) that you might use.

The basic SQL is shown below. This outputs rows of json data. With an additional step these can be combined into a block of data. The provided fiddle can be used to tweak the output to the desired final format.

**SQL:**

```
SELECT 
  book,
  CONCAT( '"', book, '" : {"', chapter, '" : [',
    GROUP_CONCAT(
      CONCAT(
        '{', 
          '"title" : "', title, '", ', 
          '"options" : "', options, '", ',
          '"answer" : "', answer, '"',
        '}'
      )
    ), 
  ']}') AS json
FROM problem GROUP BY book, chapter;
```

**JSON:** The query output validates in [JSON Lint](http://jsonlint.com/).

```
{
  "Addition": {
    "Chapter 1": [
      {
        "title": "8 + 8 = ?",
        "options": "18,17,16,15",
        "answer": "16"
      },
      {
        "title": "? + 12 = 18",
        "options": "15,17,16,6",
        "answer": "6"
      }
    ]
  }
}, ...
```